# Set specific validation rule in UpdateView

Tags: python, django

I set an UpdateView class to update data of user's markers. I have a Marker model with a field category. I want to have one and only "Where I live" category marker in all the user's markers. Is there a way to create a function in the UpdateView class to invalidate the form if there are more than one "Where I live" markers.

```
class UpdateMarkerView(UpdateView):
    model = Marker
    fields = ["name", "description", "category"]
    template_name = "map/detail.html"
    success_url = "/"
```

```
class Marker(models.Model):
    WIL = "WIL"
    WIWG = "WIWG"
    WIW = "WIW"
    IDK = "IDK"
    
    CATEGORY_MARKER = [(WIL,"Where I live"), (WIWG, "Where I want to go"),(WIW,"Where I went"),(IDK,"I don't know")]
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True, null=True,on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.fields.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.fields.CharField(max_length=100)
    lat = models.fields.DecimalField(default=False, max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    lon = models.fields.DecimalField(default=False, max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = CATEGORY_MARKER, default = IDK)
```

I've already done it with a basic function but I can't find a way to do it with a generic view if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `form_valid` method for the general answer.

But if you want to return an invalid form when there was more than 1 "Where I Live" category, you can write it like this:

```
class UpdateMarkerView(UpdateView):
    model = Marker
    fields = ["name", "description", "category"]
    template_name = "map/detail.html"
    success_url = "/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        if data.get("category") == "WIL":
           if Marker.objects.filter(category="WIL").count() >= 1:
              form.add_error('category', 'This category already exists.')
              return self.form_invalid(form)
        else:
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

First we check that the category selected by the user is "WIL", then
if there is more than 1 category(WIL), we add an error to the form and
return the invalid form.

You can also change `count` to the `exists` in the query, because it means that one already exists and this is the second.